# Windows 10 > Control Panel > Mail > Explorer.exe > Appliction not Found

Tags: windows-10, email, user-profiles, microsoft-outlook-2016

Is there anyway I can delete all mail profiles in Windows 10 without launching Outlook 2016?

Recent Windows 10 Auto-Updates broke this method shown below:

[image]

That use to bring up this dialog:

[image]

Is there a command I can use to bring that up?

Comment: What is the connection between your screen shot and deleting profiles?

Comment: Well, for the last 10 years or more you could delete profiles by the method shown in that screenshot.

Comment: Well clearly you are missing some steps. Running mail does not delete profiles.

Comment: It used to bring up this: [screenshot](http://neartalk.com/ss/2017-10-07_004_758x491.png).  Clearly, you are not aware of this behavior that was the case for several years.

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved it by reinstalling the office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out myself by combing the registry and the file system.

**In the registry, I deleted the profiles from here:**

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\

**On the file system I delete them from here:**

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Google Apps Sync

**However, most people would likely find the files here:**

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office

**or sometimes here:**

C:\Users\UserName\Documents\outlook*

Windows 10 Auto-Updates break more sh*t than do sphincters.

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there anyway I can delete all mail profiles in Windows 10?

> A profile consists of accounts, data files, and settings that specify
>   where your email messages are saved.
>
> 1. Exit Outlook.
> 2. Open Control Panel by doing one of the following:
>
>    - In Windows 8 and Windows 10, choose Start and type Control Panel.
>    - In Windows Vista and Windows 7, choose Start > Control Panel.
> 3. Open Mail by doing one of the following:
>
>    - In Windows 10, choose User Accounts > Mail.
>    - In all other versions of Windows, choose Mail.
>
>      Note:  The Mail icon appears after Outlook starts for the first time.
> 4. Choose Show Profiles.
> 5. Select a profile.
> 6. Click Remove.

Source [Remove a Profile](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-a-profile-d5f0f365-c10d-4a97-aa74-3b38e40e7cdd)

Comment: Thanks, but those steps produce the [same issue](http://neartalk.com/ss/2017-10-07_005_1199x623.png).

Answer (score 0):

@LonnieBest The answer to your original question: how can you manipulate Outlook profiles if the control panel "Mail" app is not working.

An answer: if you open Outlook, Choose the FILE menu on top left then click the drop-down option on the ACCOUNT SETTINGS button you will find two references to profile managing at the bottom of the pop-up menu [image: Accessing Profile Manager]
If you select either of these options it will open a tool with the same interface as the control panel MAIL app [image: Profile Manager]

Comment: Thanks. However, the first sentence of my question stipulates: "without launching Outlook 2016".

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this looking for an answer, Run 'outlook /safe' and it should load a Choose Profile screen where you can also choose Properties to examine data files, delete etc